# Syntax of phrase "The word cancer"

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

> "On one of the mornings of disposal, a man from a second-hand bookstore visited us, bought several hundred books, and told us of the death of his brother, **the word cancer** exploding in the living room like a time bomb detonated by his grief"
>
> <sub>E.B. White, *The Points of My Compass*, *Goodbye to 48th Street*, *Turtle Bay*, November 12, 1957</sub>

Is *cancer* an appositive of "the word"? If not then what?

Comment: We need context, if only to determine whether it should be *the word 'cancer'* or whether *word* is being used as an adjective (improbable but technically what your version means)

Comment: The full sentence: "On one of the mornings of disposal, a man from a second-hand bookstore visited us, bought several hundred books, and told us of the death of his brother, the word cancer exploding in the living room like a time bomb detonated by his grief."

Answer (score 5):

This is from the 1957 essay "Good-bye to Forty-eighth Street" by E. B. White.  The final phrase is actually

> ..., the word "cancer" exploding in the living room ....

The quotes are there to indicate that the reference is to the word for the disease and not the disease itself.  This makes the quoted text an appositive since it identifies or renames the immediately preceding word "word."

Answer (score -1):

I did misread the original question -- yes, "the word" and "cancer" are in apposition to each other.  But they're embedded in an absolute phrase, just in case you needed to know that.

It's actually an [absolute phrase](http://www.englishgrammar.org/absolute-phrase/), explained in this way:

When a participle and the noun that comes before it together forms an independent phrase, the structure is often called an absolute phrase.

Here are a couple of examples:

```
 The children ran down the hill, *their mothers [noun] trailing [participle] behind them*.

 *The party [noun] having finally ended [participle],* we started cleaning up the debris.
```

So in this case,

```
 the word cancer [noun] exploding [participle] in the living room like a time bomb detonated by his grief
```

has the same format.  It follows the pattern of an absolute phrase.